# Rails strange behaviour on "not null" column

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a model called `Order`, it has a column called `amount` which has "not null" constraint. When I'm saving a order instance with nil amount, it throws an error "PG::NotNullViolation: ERROR: null value in column "amount" violates not-null constraint" instead of return false.

However, I have another model `User` which also has a "not null" column `email`, when I'm saving an user object with `nil` email, it doesn't throw an error but return false.

I'm just wondering which one is normal. If the first one is normal behaviour, then what's the point of checking return value of `object.save` since it won't return false but throw an error if anything wrong.

Comment: You are missing a `validates :amount, presence: true` on your `Order` model

Comment: Then something is different about your actions with these models. You might be validating presence of `amount` in your order and not validate presence of `email` in `User`, which will not make Rails complain about the invalid model, but the database will.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rails will trigger *rails* validations during the `save` method, and if those fail, you'll get a `false` back.  If you're missing a validation in rails, in this case a presence validation, then it will pass on whatever values you have to your database, where they will fail, exactly as you have described.

If you want rails to ensure the validity of your data, you'll need to tell rails what is valid, not just the database.